# bitbucket authentication failing

Tags: git, bitbucket

I keep my code in bitbucket.  Without warning  git pull just hangs and after a long wait says to check if i have access.  My login for bitbucket website works fine.

1. Deleting all my keychain entries for bitbucket.org and relogging in manually didn't help anything.
2. Following the instructions for caching credentials didn't help either:
   https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html#PermanentlyauthenticatingwithGitrepositories-Usingcredentialcaching

I can't find a git command for checking status of my authentication.  Atlassian recently merged bitbucket accounts with atlassian accounts. Anybody else found a solution to this?

I'm on mac osx  10.11.5. El Capitan.

The error I get is:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree fetch origin 
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Operation timed out 
Here's the error message delivered after several minutes: 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists. 
Completed with errors, see above
```

Comment: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree fetch origin 
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Operation timed out
Here's the error message delivered after several minutes: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Completed with errors, see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Operation timed out
```

Your computer is having trouble connecting. Try running `traceroute bitbucket.org` to see what the trouble is. Maybe reboot your router. Either way the problem isn't with auth but the connection in the first place.

Comment: It was issues with the particular network I was on blocking ports.  Everything else I was doing on the Internet worked thus the rabbit trail regarding bitbucket.org